# Parse array in JSON using JsonPath in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am using jayway JsonPath library to parse the JSON using the path given. I am able to get the string value if I give the correct path. But I want to get the list of maps when I give the path if its an array. For example, I have a JSON like below:

```
{
    "employees": {
        "company": "Google",
        "people": [{
            "name": "John",
            "age": 25,
            "location": "zurich"
        },
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": 27,
            "location": "Lucerene"
        }]
    }
}
```

Below is the code I am using to parse the json.

if I give the path `$.employees.people`, I am getting the String, But I need to List of Maps. Below is the code I am using to Parse Json using jsonpath.

```
DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonStr);
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.employees.people");
List<Maps<String,String>> jsonList = documentContext.read(jsonPath) //But this is returning String
```

Anyone suggest proper approach to get what I expected.

Comment: Using [online tool](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) your `JSON` path for given `JSON` payload returns list of maps. There is no `Maps` class, instead of `List<Maps<String,String>>` use `List<Map<String,String>>`

Answer (score -1):

try using,

```
DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonStr);
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.employees.people[?]");
List<Maps<String,String>> jsonList = documentContext.read(jsonPath);
```

if you need more details. [readmore...](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath)